# newbie: tips on how to cleanup , improve, arrange, shorten model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, code-formatting

I find my models getting more and more clumped and messy. below is my actual user model, any suggestions on cleaning things up and arranging things for better readability?

Im getting frustrated by the unreadability of this all, so any general thoughts on this code are welcome. I really like code that does the same to be positioned together but like I have now is just one big bulk unreadable mess.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  email                  :string(255)     default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string(255)     default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string(255)
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer(4)      default(0)
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string(255)
#  password_salt          :string(255)
#  confirmation_token     :string(255)
#  confirmed_at           :datetime
#  confirmation_sent_at   :datetime
#  unconfirmed_email      :string(255)
#  failed_attempts        :integer(4)      default(0)
#  unlock_token           :string(255)
#  locked_at              :datetime
#  authentication_token   :string(255)
#  username               :string(255)
#  is_blocked             :boolean(1)
#  is_deleted             :boolean(1)
#  role                   :string(255)
#  slug                   :string(255)
#  created_at             :datetime        not null
#  updated_at             :datetime        not null
#  last_seen              :datetime
#  credits                :integer(4)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable,
         :encryptable,
         :confirmable,
         :lockable,
         :timeoutable,
         :lastseenable
  #:omniauthable

  attr_accessible :username,
                  :login,
                  :email,
                  :password,
                  :password_confirmation,
                  :remember_me,
                  :profile_attributes,
                  :is_moderated,
                  :is_blocked,
                  :is_deleted,
                  :credits,
                  :role,
                  :confirmed_at,
                  :last_seen,
                  :invite_code


  attr_accessor :login
  #attr_accessor :invite_code

  has_one :profile
  has_one :account

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  before_create :default_values


  # AFTER CREATE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  after_create :add_account

  def add_account
    self.create_account

  end

  def default_values
    self.credits = -1
    self.invite_code = invite_code
    #self.reset_authentication_token!
    beta = Beta.where(:code => invite_code).first
    beta.used = 1
    beta.save
  end


  # ROLES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users
  ROLES = %w[admin default vip]


  # VALIDATIONS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  before_validation { |u| u.username.downcase! }
  before_validation { |u| u.email.downcase! }

  validates_uniqueness_of :username,
                          :email,
                          :case_sensitive => false

  validates_presence_of :email,
                        :username,
                        :invite_code

  validates :username,
            :exclusion => {:in => ["admin", "root", "administrator", "superuser", "myhost", "support", "contact", "chat", "boo"],
                           :message => "is reserved"}


  validate :check_email, :on => :create
  validate :check_invite_code, :on => :create

  def check_invite_code
    errors.add(:invite_code, "Invalid code") unless Beta.where(:code => invite_code, :used => 0).first
  end

# Devise
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && !is_deleted
  end


# Devise
  def confirm!
    #welcome_message
    #super
  end

# Devise
  def soft_delete
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
  end


  def is_moderated?
    return self.is_moderated
  end

  def is_online?
    if self.last_seen < 10.minutes.ago
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  private

  def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    if self.role.blank?
      self.role = "default"
    end
  end


  def welcome_message
    #::Devise.mailer.welcome_instructions(self).deliver
    ::Devise.mailer.welcome_instructions(self).deliver
  end


  def check_email

    host = email.split("@").last
    username = email.split("@").first

    reserved_word_filters = %w(admin hostmaster root support )

    if /.*(#{reserved_word_filters.join("|")}).*\@/.match(email)
      errors.add(:email, "Invalid username in email")
    end

    if email.include? 'myhost'
      errors.add(:email, "Invalid email")
    end

  end


# DEVISE:  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  protected


  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", {:value => login.strip.downcase}]).first
  end


end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also get in the habit of treating booleans as first class expressions. For example,

```
def is_online?
  if self.last_seen < 10.minutes.ago
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

is more clearly written as:

```
def is_online?
  last_seen < 10.minutes.ago
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I would do to clean up models is to modularize them a bit. DHH himself posted a great [example gist](https://gist.github.com/1014971) showing how to clean up a model that had gotten too large. I don't think yours is particularly too big, but if you wanted to move all the devise stuff into its own module, it certainly would make your model a bit more tidy.

Answer (score 2):

1.
You have `return` statements all over your code. Unless you are returning something prematurely in a method, the return of the last statement in a method is what Ruby returns automatically. Like so:

```
def square(x)
  val = x**2
  return val
end
```

can be shortened to:

```
def square(x)
  x**2
end
```

It's a contrived example, but there it is.

2.
Many of the `self`s are redundant. In an model instance's scope, when setting an attribute to a value or calling a method, you do not need to prepend `self`, since that method/variable is already being called from that same scope.